# Fix Mongo query in Lumen

Tags: mongodb, laravel, lumen, jenssegers-mongodb

I have a query in the lumen. But it does not work. The query is :

```
return Order::whereBetween('source_longitude', [$minLon_try_one, $maxLon_try_one])
        ->whereBetween('source_latitude',[51.365807806703,51.454384193297])
        ->where('status','=','pending')
        ->where('created_at','<=', 2016-04-07 12:00:35)
        ->where('created_at','>=', 2016-04-07 11:55:35)
        ->orWhere(function($query)
        {
                    $query->whereBetween('source_longitude', [51.321519613407, 51.498672386593])
                    ->whereBetween('source_latitude',[35.612195271526,35.756086728473])
                    ->where('status','=','pending')
                    ->where('created_at','<=',2016-04-07 11:55:35)
                    ->where('created_at','>=',2016-04-07 11:50:35);
        }
        )->get();
```

But when I remove `orWhere` function from the query I get expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably using `orWhere` a little bit wrong. You need to put where to another where to execute query properly. What You are doing now is something like that `where a is 1 and b is 2 or (c is 3 and d is 4)`, but I believe, You want to do something like that `where (a is 1 and b is 2) or (c is 3 and d is 4)`
Try this one:

```
    return Order::where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereBetween('source_longitude', [$minLon_try_one, $maxLon_try_one])
            ->whereBetween('source_latitude', [51.365807806703, 51.454384193297])
            ->where('status', '=', 'pending')
            ->where('created_at', '<=', '2016-04-07 12:00:35')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', '2016-04-07 11:55:35');
    })->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->whereBetween('source_longitude', [51.321519613407, 51.498672386593])
            ->whereBetween('source_latitude', [35.612195271526, 35.756086728473])
            ->where('status', '=', 'pending')
            ->where('created_at', '<=', '2016-04-07 11:55:35')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', '2016-04-07 11:50:35');
    })->get();
```

Comment: thanks . Sorry, I just have a question how can i update status field when each order created_at past 20 minutes